# how to run a single test from testngxml/Maven

Tags: maven

I have a set of tests defined in testng xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="P1 Test Suite" verbose="1">

<test name="test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>


<test name="test2">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.class2"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="test3">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test3"/>
    </classes>
</test>


</suite>
```

What I want to achieve is run only one test class at a time, say I want to run only "test1" at a particular time and no other. How do I achieve this? This needs to be done from maven command line. Any suggestion would be of great help. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to maven surefire help [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) : - can jump to "Running 'testnames' in test tag" section.  Parametrize the property value section with any property say ${testNames} and pass -DtestNames to the mvn test command.

Comment: Nope, tried this, still itexecutes all the tests from top to bottom

Comment: Paste what you have tried - pom surefire configuration. maven run command

Comment: <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.18.1</version>
     <configuration>
      <argLine>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</argLine>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
       <suiteXmlFile>${testng.dir}${file.separator}P1UtaSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
       <systemPropertyVariables>
       <testnames>${testname}</testnames>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
      
     </configuration>
    </plugin>

Comment: and this is the maven command i gave :                        

 mvn test -DtestSuite=P1UtaSuite.xml  -Dtestname=test1

Comment: Can you follow the surefire way.  It works for me.<suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
      <properties>
               <property>
                 <name>testnames</name>
                 <value>${testt}</value>
               </property>
             </properties>

Comment: mvn test -Dtestt=Test1

Comment: Now i get a MojoFailure Exception ;it says no tests to run/compile

Comment: I hope you corrected your xml file..is the xml file running as such?

Comment: yes, mine is already set sth like this :
<suiteXmlFile>${testng.dir}${file.separator}P1UtaSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
which takes parameters from smwhr else

Comment: I used **mvn test -Dsuite=oneSuite.xml -Dtestname=oneTest** but didn't worked. Any other ideas?

Comment: This is not working for me. Can someone please help?